# Create Website on RPi using Windows IDE

Tags: pi-3, software-development, web, javascript, ide

I'm really new to using an RPi as a web server. I want to develop a couple simple web sites, probably using Javascript for now, maybe Python. I've set up Apache, Python, and MySQL on the RPi3, running fine. I was going to use MS Visual Studio as my IDE, but that looks like a non-starter for the moment (correct me if I'm wrong...)

Seems like Komposer should work, and I've installed it, but I'm having trouble connecting with the RPi. I think it's simple setup issues with the RPi....

[image: Komposer Setup Dialog:]

My project is "FunWithTilio", and my RPi is located at 192.168.2.115. What would be the HTTP address of my homepage?

How can I create a "name" for that IP address on my Windows 10 machine?

If my username is "Jim", is there a group Jim needs to be added to or something like that to resolve permissions?

I need to install Twilio API's. Do I install them on the target RPi, or the Win10 machine, or both?

Thanks guys. I appreciate anything you can help with....

Answer (score 1):

You didn't make it clear enough about why publish isn't working.  But from that screenshot I suspect it is expecting an ftp server to be installed on your Pi.  That can be done, but it is here is a workaround that might work for you, using native Pi stuff, plus Apache:

Instead of using publish, I would first try transferring the files directly.

Save your files on your hard drive, obviously.

Verify that apache2 is installed on the pi by putting its IP address into your browser like so:

```
http://192.168.2.115/
```

If you don't get the Apache "It works!" message then install Apache like this:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Then try again and make sure you get the message.

Scroll down a bit and it will tell you what directory to use for your HTML files.

Maybe you knew all that part already.

So then to transfer your files you do this:

Make sure SSH is enabled on the Pi - you can use raspi-config for that in a terminal window.  You may need to reboot.

Then install FileZilla on your PC.

Use it to make a connection to the Pi via Wifi.  When you set up the new connection in site manager (ctrl-s) make sure it uses SFTP and a "normal" login, then put in your username and password.  Username is usually "pi"

When you connect for the first time it will want you to accept the public key of your Pi.  Then it will connect smoothly from then on.

It can transfer your HTML files into your www directory or into a subdirectory you make.   You will be able to see the files they used.    Make sure your initial filename is correct, or add yours to the URL when you test it.

Then test it in your browser.

It should work the same as if you did a publish.

Creating names is done either by modifying your host file (c:/windows/system32/etc/hosts) or in a DNS.  Not by file transfers.

If you need multiple sites on one Pi then put them in separate subdirectories.

Or if you are a mastermind, look at the Apache configuration file and see what you can do with that.

Comment: OK, thanks. Pi is up and running with ssh and apache. I've confirmed that. Thanks for the advice, anyway, you never know. I also knew the file I needed to put on Win10 was "hosts", I just couldn't remember where to put it. Again, thanks. Last time I did this, I was never able to make Komposer actually publish. My SSH client uses SFTP, so that'll work. OK, I'll get to work.